# followers of X, excluding followers of Y in single JOIN query (many-to-many through)

Tags: python, mysql, django

The answer to my question might very well be "thats the best you can do", but I am hoping I am just looking at this too long and missing something....

Referencing this [article on Asymmetrical Relationships](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/), I am looking at the 'mutual friends relationship' query. Here are the models from the article:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship', 
                                           symmetrical=False, 
                                           related_name='related_to')

    def get_friends(self):
        return self.relationships.filter(
            to_people__from_person=self,
            from_people__to_person=self)

class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='from_people')
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='to_people')
```

The `get_friends()` results in a JOIN query.

The query I want to do is "People following person_A but not following person_B". The relationship many-to-many removes a bunch of the work, leaving only a simple query requirement on my part... So I have this:

```py
person_A.relationships\
    .filter(from_people__to_person=person_A)\
    .exclude(from_people__to_person=person_B)
```

The result contains a subquery:

```sql
SELECT `person`.`id` FROM `person` 
INNER JOIN `relationship` ON (`person`.`id` = `relationship`.`to_person_id`) 
INNER JOIN `relationship` T4 ON (`person`.`id` = T4.`from_person_id`) 
WHERE (
    `relationship`.`from_person_id` = 178  
    AND T4.`to_person_id` = 178  
    AND NOT (`person`.`id` IN (
        SELECT U1.`from_person_id` FROM `relationship` U1 
        WHERE (U1.`to_person_id` = 191  AND U1.`from_person_id` IS NOT NULL)
    ))
)
```

Does this kind of exclusion query imply a needed subquery or am I just missing some simple adjustment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tables (maybe simplified) look something along the lines of:

#### person:

```
id   |   name
-------------
1    |   Zane
2    |   Jeff
3    |   Troy
5    |   Steffan
6    |   Lolo
7    |   Katrina
```

---

#### relationship:

```
from_id   |   to_id
-------------------
1         |   5
1         |   6
2         |   5
2         |   1
2         |   5
3         |   1
5         |   1
5         |   2
7         |   5
```

Where `from_id` is a follower of `to_id`, and a person can't follow his or her self.

And we want to *get all followers of `5` who are not also followers of `1`*, we would desire this result:

```
id   |   name
--------------
1    |   Zane
7    |   Katrina
```

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT    a.id, a.name
FROM      person a
JOIN      relationship b ON a.id = b.from_id
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT from_id
          FROM   relationship
          WHERE  to_id = 1
          ) c ON b.from_id = c.from_id
WHERE     b.to_id = 5 AND
          c.from_id IS NULL
```

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6d37/1/0)

Comment: Nice examples. So it does appear that I should be expecting a subquery for this solution right? My django query example generating a slightly larger version of this I think. I assume yours would be more efficient.

Comment: @jdi, I'm not really familiar with python/django, but in my SQL example above, I'm using a **subselect** within a `LEFT JOIN` which is different (and more efficient) than an `IN` **subquery** in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed to know, thanks! I was using an inefficient subselect.

Comment: I've got no answers on this [other SQL question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567422/implications-of-insert-ignore-vs-two-step-query-for-batch-inserts), if you have time.